# Meaning of 'POL' on component?

Tags: schematics

I have this component on a schematic and no idea what `POL` means.

[image]

Here is the a more complete schematics of this washing machine:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Power On Light.

And I think a circle with the 4 lines coming out of it is a standard electrical wiring symbol for a light.

Comment: Yes, reading the diagram more thoroughly, i found that they write a explanation for all the abbravations used and POL, was indeed Power On Light.